# Room: Adding an extra column

Tags: kotlin, android-room

I am creating an application using Room/Kotlin and would like to add an additional column but I am unable to get the second column to show. The application works on the emulator but will not show the data correctly i.e. pb and then the value for the that pb. It will only show the first column.

Dao

```
@Dao
interface PbDao {


    @Query("SELECT * from pb_table ORDER BY pb ASC")
    fun getAlphabetizedPbs(): LiveData<List<Pb>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(pb: Pb)

    @Query("DELETE FROM pb_table")
    suspend fun deleteAll()
}
```

Pb

```
@Entity(tableName = "pb_table")

data class Pb(
    @PrimaryKey//(autoGenerate = true) var uid:Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "pb") val pb: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "pb_value") val pb_value: Double = 0.0)
```

db

```
@Database(entities = [Pb::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class PersonalBestDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun pbDao(): PbDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: PersonalBestDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(
            context: Context,
            scope: CoroutineScope
        ): PersonalBestDatabase {
            // if the INSTANCE is not null, then return it,
            // if it is, then create the database
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    PersonalBestDatabase::class.java,
                    "pb_database"
                )
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .addCallback(PbDatabaseCallback(scope))
                    .build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                instance
            }
        }

        private class PbDatabaseCallback(
            private val scope: CoroutineScope
        ) : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
            override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                super.onOpen(db)

                INSTANCE?.let { database ->
                    scope.launch {
                        populateDatabase(database.pbDao())
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        suspend fun populateDatabase(pbDao: PbDao) {
            pbDao.deleteAll()

            var pb = Pb("Squat", 120.0)
            pbDao.insert(pb)

            pb = Pb("Bench Press", 65.0)
            pbDao.insert(pb)

            pb = Pb("Deadlift", 142.5)
            pbDao.insert(pb)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you updated your database version? can you please edit the post with the log errors?

Comment: @Shermano I've just updated the post with the database and log errors.

Comment: can you just change version to 2 on Database class and check if works? The logs that you posted doesn't seem to be related with the actual error

Comment: @Shermano thanks I tried that but it still isn't working properly. I don't have any errors now but I can't get the second column to display. I think I am missing some code for the second column to work. I have edited the post to give more details.

Comment: Your code seems to be all right, you inserted new values and the new column is not returning  on getAlphabetizedPb() ?

Comment: @Shermano No unfortunately it's only showing the one column

Comment: thats odd you're debuggin or you're showing on screen? if you're showing pls post this code as well

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: How you're checking that the other column is not showing?

Comment: @Shermano on the emulator and it works fine without any errors but it just isn't showing the second column.

Comment: can you edit with the code that is showing the values of getAlphabetizedPbs() ?

Comment: I have tried to edit pbDao but it didn't work. Do I need to update the dao for the second column?

Comment: No you don't, i would like to see where on the code these values are showing in the screen

Comment: @Shermano I have added the db to the post which shows the values on the screen (except the values for the second column).